# How to generate colors in GWT and dynamically apply it in CSS

Tags: css, gwt, random, colors

In an application I need to use different colors. That is I want to dynamically generate colors as well as make changes in the `CSS` properties. I have used

```
draw.getElement().getStyle().setProperty(); // Where draw is my flowpanel
```

but I get the error as not in camelCase format. Also since I'm using the above method I need to pass the parameters as Strings, but if I Google about generating different colors then they all in different formats.

How do I achieve that in GWT and how do I apply that generated color in `CSS` class?

Answer (score 1):

All the properties you pass should be in CamelCase format, and there is nothing wrong with it, just change for example "background-color" to "backgroundColor" and it will be correctly set.
So this way you can change colors dynamically. Modifying css is not necessary for the purpose (and not feasible).

Answer (score 0):

Can do by method provided by GWT, like
`draw.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor(String value);`

Your problem is instead of ordinary '-' formatting, use camelCase formatting
so that `background-color` becomes `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

Note that when setting a style property, your need to use camel case for the property name.

```
draw.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("background-color", "colorname");//gives error


draw.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("backgroundColor", "colorname");//will works
```

And try to use [W3C slandered color codes](http://www.docsteve.com/DocSteve/TechNotes/color_test.html)   .Those codes support by all standered browsers

There You can find unofficial color codes also :P